# Rails: Display user name, if user not exist, display 'Anonymous' Instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I write:`<%= @blog.user.name || 'Anonymous' %>`

But when @blog.user is `nil`, it will report `undefined method name for nil:NilClass` 
How to get around this and display `Anonymous` Instead?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is perfect case to use `ActiveSupport's` [`Object#try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) method:

```
<%= @blog.user.try(:name) || 'Anonymous' %>
```

This way you call `name` method on `@blog.user` only if it responds to this method (which isn't true if it's `nil`).

Comment: it's not me though I have different idea :)

Answer (score 3):

I would do this using the ? operator

```
<%= @blog.user ? @blog.user.name : 'Anonymous' %>
```