# Rails error when user did not input associated value through form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, associations

I currently using stable rails 4.2 with ruby 2.2 and postgresql. I have run into the problem where I have user not input associated value to the form

Ex. If I have **Post** associated with **Category** and I have select box to select value. If user select a value and submit, everything working perfectly. However when user not select any value from the select box, rails will throw this error in show page;

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

If i use this method

```
@post.category.name
```

I knew that it's error because it got no value. but I have used the same method before in Rails 4.1.0 with Ruby 2.0.0 and sqlite. Everything was fine and I don't need any extra actions. The fields with no value were just returned blank and no error.

I have checked association in model & database, they are correct.
Checked my controller's strong parameter, instantiate, they looks ok.

How can I avoid or get rid of this problem?

Comment: `nil.name` always raises an error (unless you implemented `NilClass#name` method), so it's pretty normal behavior. To fix it, you can use this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300851/rails-display-user-name-if-user-not-exist-display-anonymous-instead/22300894#22300894

Comment: Even if you checked it, you should still paste the code

Comment: Thank you @MarekLipka , it's working! this is the answer I'm looking for. I have one more question, how can you implement that on looping checkbox like this  ` <% post.categories.each do |obj| %>
    <%= obj.name %>
  <% end %> `